# How to find out easily if one or more Components have been deleted in Tridion?

Tags: 2011

I would like to find out, if Components have been deleted in Tridion.

For example, I had a Component `A` and it's been deleted from Tridion and I have searched the same in Tridion but it's not available.

I understand that deleted Components will not be available in Tridion. But maybe I can get a report of deleted Components?

Comment: I think you should be more clear about in which context you need to find out if a component has been deleted. Do you want a report of deleted components?, do you want to execute some logic when a component is deleted?

Comment: I see, you can use Event System to store the deleted components information in an external storage once they are deleted.

Comment: Thank you Eric, do you mean if there is an external storage thing then i can restore the same and there is no other way to get it restore or find out?

Answer (score 4):

More than 10 years ago when Tridion version 4 was the current release (and before versions 5, 2009, 2011,and 2013) there was a trash can feature and all deleted items would go there before being finally deleted.  However, we noticed almost all customers did not use this feature and it was removed from the system by vesion 5.

It sounds like you have 2 needs:

1. Log when a user deletes an item.  This is best achieved with the
   Event System, as Eric suggests, and you listen for the Delete event.
   You could best store it in a DB and use an ORM like EF, ORMLite, etc
   to store and retrieve them.
2. Restoring a deleted item.  This is a more difficult task - as you will need to re-create the item.  The best starting place is to save the XML of the original item in the DB when it is being deleted, so you can use it to make it again later.  In the worst case scenario, you could show the user the text of the item and they can create it manually themselves.

Both of these actions would need to be logged in your own custom database.  I would suggest to start small and solve it step by step, focusing on 1 item type at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems a bit incomplete and vague, but I would try to give some pointers.

By default it is not possible to figure out if a component has been deleted (unless a specific custom code has been written for this very purpose).

If you are planning to do so, then you can write a custom code using Event Systems based on TOM.NET API.

If you do not have such code in place and want to figure out "if a component has already been deleted" then you may try to find out by re-storing older Content Manager database.

I hope it helps